# Find limit of $\left(1-\frac{2}{5n+5}\right)^{3n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having difficulties with finding this limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{5n+5}\right)^{3n}$$

According to my notes from lecture I need to make it to this form: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$

I have no bloody idea how to solve this, but I've solved similar exercises like:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)^n = e^2$$ and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.
Note that
$$\left(1-\frac{2}{5n+5}\right)^{3n}=\left(\left(1-\frac{2}{5n+5}\right)^{-\frac{5n+5}{2}}\right)^{-\frac{6n}{5n+5}}.$$

Comment: Oh, it get it now. Now I see what was done there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

write $$(1- \frac{2}{5n+5})^{3n}=e^{\log_e(1- \frac{2}{5n+5})^{3n} }=e^{3n\log_e(1- \frac{2}{5n+5}) }.$$

When $n$ goes to infinity $\log(1- \frac{2}{5n+5})$ is asymptotic to $\frac{-2}{5n+5}$. So you get $$e^{3n \log_e(1- \frac{2}{5n+5})}\sim e^{\frac{-6n}{5n+5}} \rightarrow e^{\frac{-6}{5}}$$ 
when $n\rightarrow + \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1-\dfrac2{5n+5}\right)^{3n}=\left(\left(1-\dfrac2{5n+5}\right)^{-(5n+5)/2}\right)^{-6n/5n+5}$$

Now $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{-6n}{5n+5}=\dfrac{-6}{5+\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac5n}=?$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{2}{5n+5})^{3n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((1-\frac{\frac{2}{5}}{n+1})^{n+1}\right)^3\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((1-\frac{\frac{2}{5}}{n+1})^{-1}\right)^3=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((1-\frac{\frac{2}{5}}{n+1})^{n+1}\right)^3(1)=e^{-\frac{6}{5}}$$